# Wear OS (Java) Scheduled notifications while sleep over network

Tags: java, android, wear-os

on my GW3 / Fossil gen 3 i developed an app (java - with android studio) that starts a sperate foreground service for notifications request that were be fetched with okhttp3 via rest call to my srv.

Very simple if there are any messages for that client within the rest call my srv returns a json with its content and my wear starts to vibrate / ring and showed up the content.

With Android 11 or 10 idk exactly an update for both clocks arrived for battery optimization on that app stops working as expected cuz there was no option to schedule tasks within sleep mode. Messages (rest calls) that should be retrieved every 10 minutes were retrieved completely asynchronously from the update mentioned, sometimes 30 minutes then again after 4 hours and so on.

Now with sdk 12 foreground services seems to be outdated and won't work anymore for such features.

Is there any way to get it work with fixed scheduled times like each 10 minutes regardless of the state of the watch (Standby / sleep mode) with rest calls and does someone have an example for such an implementation ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.